# Combining gyroscope and compass to navigate in cities?

Tags: gyroscope, magnetometer, compass

I am developing a navigation app which combines compass and gyroscope to withstand magnetic field disturbances which can be found in cities.

I am able to know what the magnetic field is supposed to be. In my location its 50μT. (Here I am hoping to find an api which gives me magnetic field from geolocation. Or I have to calculate it). Then I am able to detect if the magnetic field is for instance +- 10μT or greater to assume there is magnetic field disturbance with the magnetometer.

Then I am hoping to use the gyroscope until I get a accurate compass reading again.

Has anyone tried this? Would it work?

Comment: Why can't you use GPS?

Comment: gps just gives me location. I am calculating which direction to go in the app. So I need to know which way the user is facing

Comment: Any map app estimates velocity vector by taking first difference of positions given by gps sensor

Comment: If you still want to use gyro and magnetometer you should look at kalman filter

Comment: doesn't the earth's magnetic field fluctuate continuously?

Comment: When reading raw data from iPhone I get a stable reading of 570 - 573 (of unknown unit: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116222). When reading calibrated data I get a stable reading of 50.0 - 50.1 μT. No it does not appear too fluctuate.